# How do I Have Different Header Rules For Elements In CSS Class

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

Okay so this is kind of hard to explain; therefore, it is also hard to search for, so I am just going to ask here.

Basically I have a CSS class that I am applying to certain DIVs. Within each class I would like to have rules that apply to certain selectors only in that DIV

For example let's say I have a CSS class like this

```
  .main_wrapper {
        text-align: center;

        h1
    {
        color: blue;
    }

    }

    .question_wrapper  {
        text-align: left;

        h1
    {
        color: red;
    }
    }
```

And then let's say I had HTML like this

```
<div class="main_wrapper">

    <h1>Test 1</h1>

    <div class="question_wrapper">

        <h1>Test 2</h1>

    </div>

</div>
```

What I would like to accomplish with CSS is have the h1 tag in the main_wrapper div be blue and the h1 tag in question_wrapper be red.

I know that the CSS I have here doesn't work but that is essentially what I am trying to accomplish.

I hope this makes sense.

If anybody has any ideas that would be great.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#combinators

Comment: Is that CSS code LESS/SASS?

Comment: You should avoid having multiple h1 elements in a document, it is rare to have more than one Most Important Heading.

Comment: @Quentin...not true any more although I understand what you are saying. http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/the-truth-about-multiple-h1-tags-in-the-html5-era--webdesign-16824

Comment: @ slister I know not why you say it doesn't work - http://jsbin.com/xidapuva/1/edit

Comment: @Paulie_D — That doesn't apply in this example (since there are no sectioning elements) and due to a lack of implementations, the new sectioning rules are only theoretical at present and should usually be avoided in practice.

Comment: @Quentin - Good point. TY

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use this:

```
.main_wrapper > h1{
   color:blue;
}

.question_wrapper > h1{
   color:red;
}
```

`>` means direct child of whats' before `>`

Answer (score 1):

You can use '>' operator for selecting child elements.

```
.main_wrapper > h1 {
color: blue;
}

.question_wrapper > h1{
color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is your SCSS

```
 .main_wrapper {
        text-align: center;

        h1
    {
        color: blue;
    }

    }

    .question_wrapper  {
        text-align: left;

        h1
    {
        color: red;
    }
    }
```

this would be your CSS

```
.main_wrapper {
  text-align: center;
}
.main_wrapper h1 {
  color: blue;
}

.question_wrapper {
  text-align: left;
}
.question_wrapper h1 {
  color: red;
}
```

...and it would work.

[**Sassmeister Gist Demo**](http://sassmeister.com/gist/10472540)

Comment: Thank you to everybody for the quick and helpful responses. It never ceases to amaze me how helpful the Stack Overflow community is.